# "maximum recursion depth exceeded" when "property" is applied to instance variable "self.x"

Tags: python

I was reading property(), which I understand is attribute access goes through the method specified in property().
But I got "RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded", when executed the following code.

```
class Property(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = "Raj"

    def gettx(self):
        print "getting x"
        return self.x

    def settx(self, val):
        print "Setting x"
        self.x = val

    def dellx(self):
        print "deleting"
        return self.x

    x = property(gettx, settx, dellx, "I'm object property")


p = Property()
print "p.x", p.x
p.x = "R"
print "p.x:", p.x
```

Is it not possible to apply property in this way. Because it worked fine when 'self.x' changed to self._x and self.__x.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The error is due to the following infinite recursion loop: you have defined a property `x` with uses the `gettx`, `settx` and `deltx` access methods, but the access methods themselves try to access the property `x` (i.e. call themselves).

You should write the code along the following lines:

```
class Property(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.__x = "Raj"  # Class private

    def gettx(self):
        print "getting x"
        return self.__x

    def settx(self, val):
        print "Setting x"
        self.__x = val

    def dellx(self):
        print "deleting"
        return self.__x

    x = property(gettx, settx, dellx, "I'm object property")
```

Comment: yep. Its works self.__x and self._x. What if I want property() for "public" instance variables for controlling its access.

Comment: The property itself (i.e. `x` in your example) is the public attribute. It requires a distinct private storage, however (i.e. `_x` or `__x`). So you're controlling the public attribute (`x`) and hiding the storage (`_x` or `__x`). Make sense?

Comment: The name "x" for property and also for instance variable confused me.
Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: And the `__x' class attribute is only private by convention. There is nothing preventing access.

Comment: This makes sense; I couldn't figure out why it was occurring either, but it's at once obvious once you realize the self-call, etc.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property):

> If c is an instance of C, c.x will invoke the getter, c.x = value will
>   invoke the setter and del c.x the deleter.

So, your code line `self.x = "Raj"` essentially calls the method `settx(self, val)`. Within that method the line `self.x = val` again calls the `settx(self, val)` method which in turn again calls the `settx(self, val)`. Thus, we have an infinite loop.

So, the correct way to set the value of the property is `self._x = value`.

Correct code:

```
class Property(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = 'Raj'

    def gettx(self):
        print "getting x"
        return self._x

    def settx(self, val):
        print "Setting x"
        self._x = val #stores the value in _x. writing self.x = val would cause an infinite loop

    def dellx(self):
        print "deleting"
        del self._x    

    x = property(gettx, settx, dellx, "I'm object property")

p = Property()
print "p.x", p.x
p.x = "R"
print "p.x:", p.x
```

Output:

```
p.x getting x
Raj
Setting x
p.x: getting x
R
```