# Setting property causes maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: python, recursion, properties

I have the following class:

```
class vehicle(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.kinds_list = ["tank", "car", "motorbike", "bike", "quad" ] 

    @property
    def kind(self):
        return self.kind

    @kind.setter
    def kind(self, x):
        if x in self.kinds_list:
            self.kind = x
        else:
            raise AttributeError('No attribute {0} found !'.format(y))
```

Setting `kind` causes a `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`, aka stack overflow.

How to re-write the setter to make it work with fixed list only?

Comment: You want only certain allowed attributes? Maybe you should look at `__slots__` instead... Either that or `__setattr__`... perhaps if you explained in a paragraph what you want to achieve...

Comment: You do realise using `self.kind = x` in the setter calls the setter again? Use a different name for the underlying attribute and the property.

Comment: @JonClements Not even remotely the cause of the stack overflow though. Your suggestion is useful in this specific case, but won't help the OP use `@property` correctly in general.

Comment: Your getter and setter are recursively defined (`self.kind = x` calls the setter again, etc). Use a "private" attribute instead, e.g. `self._kind`.

Comment: Also, is there a reason you're using a checked `kinds_list` instead of just defining `Tank`, `Car`, [etc] classes that inherit from `vehicle`?

Comment: I am learninig, and you`ve given me new topics, especially the inherit classes example was added to TODO list. Thanks

Answer (score 41):

The reason you reached the maximum recursion depth is that inside your setter, you do `self.kind = ...`, which recursively calls the same setter. You should store the value as some private attribute, just rename `self.kind` to `self._kind`.

```
class vehicle(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.kinds_list = ["tank", "car", "motorbike", "bike", "quad" ] 

    @property
    def kind(self):
        return self._kind

    @kind.setter
    def kind(self, x):
        if x in self.kinds_list:
            self._kind = x
        else:
            raise ValueError('{0} is an illegal kind of vehicle!'.format(y))
```

This is not a real private attribute like in other languages, since nothing prevents you from accessing `my_vehicle._kind`. By convention in python, everything starting with an underscore is private and shouldn't normally be touched outside of the class. Or [as they say](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Objects): python is for consenting adults ;).

I also slightly modified the error message in the setter.

Comment: Thanks, fixed. The main use for `AttributeError` is probably inside `__getattribute__`, when you try to access `my_object.illegal_attribute`. `ValueError` seems more appropriate here.

Comment: I`m just learning as you most likely know by now.
Private attribute is next topic to learn then. Thanks!

Comment: Don't apologize for still learning new things, everyone started like that. Just keep asking questions in a smart way (which you did) and first do a search to check if a question was already asked before (since similar things [have been asked before](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14749225/2647279)). Please accept the answer if you are happy.