# Applying property setter logic in __init__

Tags: python, class, properties, setter

I read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14749312/9871463) with setting an attribute in python and getting *maximum recursion depth error*.

How and where should I check and test a value when setting an attribute ? I know I can check it in `setter`, but is it good to check it in `__init__()` of an class ? If I check it in `__init__()`, then my `setter` and `__init__` have repeated code.

Example of my code:

```
class RealNumber:

    def __init__(self, real):
        self._real = real  # NEED TO TEST IT BEFORE ASSIGNMENT
                           # TEST IS SAME AS IN SETTER

    @property
    def real(self):
        return self._real

    @real.setter
    def real(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, int):
            self._real = value
        else:
            raise ValueError('Can not set real part with value {}'.format(value))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply issue `self.real = real` in `__init__`. The property setter is already in effect.

```
class RealNumber:
    def __init__(self, real):
        self.real = real

    @property
    def real(self):
        return self._real

    @real.setter
    def real(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, int):
            self._real = value
        else:
            raise ValueError('Can not set real part with value {}'.format(value))


r = RealNumber(3)
print(r._real)
print(r.real)
print(vars(r))

try:
    RealNumber('bogus')
except ValueError:
    print('error as expected')
```

Output:

```
3
3
{'_real': 3}
error as expected
```

Comment: So we are calling getter and setter in constructor automatically ? And is good design naming variable `self._real` when getter, setter and init use `self.real` ?

Comment: @DinkoPehar With `my_instance.real = ...` you always trigger your setter, in this case `my_instance` is `self`. The setter does not care whether the code doing the setting operates from outside the class or within a method of that class. I don't see anything wrong with your naming conventions.

Comment: Thank you. I'll use this form when designing a class blueprints.

Comment: @DinkoPehar you might also want to look into the topic of [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3.7/howto/descriptor.html) if you need *reusable* properties.

Comment: p.s.:  in the getter and setter methods, you still have to use self._real (prefixed with underscore). Somehow, when I remove the underscore of my getter and return it without any string modifications, python will still work fine. However, when I put it inside of a f-string, it recurses indefinitely as expected.